# Group Membership on Linux

Tags: linux, user-management, groups

I am adding a user using

`useradd -d /home/testuser -m -g usergroup -s /bin/bash testuser`

The group 'usergroup' already exists. This command runs fine and the user is created. However, when I try to use it to write to a folder that only has group write permission, it says permission denied. When I look in /etc/group , the user is not in the list of users that belong to 'usergroup'. Is there an extra step I am missing?

**Update**

forgot to mention that when I add the user to /etc/group, he has the correct access.

id:

```
uid=524(testuser) gid=524(usergroup) groups=524(usergroup)
```

ls:

```
drwxrwxr-x  site usergroup                                  /usr/local/test/
```

Comment: If your primary group is `usergroup` you needn't be listed for that group in `/etc/group`. Please post the output of `id` (when you are `testuser`) and the output of `ls -ldZ /path/to/folder`

Comment: Show the permissions and ownership of the directory you're unable to write to.

Comment: Are you using ACLs? What does `getfacl /usr/local/test/` say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a user to a group IN ADDITION to their "personal" group, you need to use the -G option.  This is probably the option you want, otherwise that user's home directory will be

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 user usergroup
```

Unless, of course, you don't want the user to have any personal stuff at all.  If you want the user to write files with the `usergroup` group when working on the shared directory, set the sgid bit on the directory (chmod g+s /usr/local/test/), this causes files created in that directory to always have the same group as the directory.

Comment: Using -G instead of -g worked, thanks.